# Rename [tags] meta tag

Tags: discussion, meta-tags

[tags](/questions/tagged/tags):

> General questions about tag usage on the main site

Perhaps it should be renamed to [tag-usage](/questions/tagged/tag-usage), because questions about retagging, merging and renaming are sometimes tagged with [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) - it's too general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to stay as it is.

If you want to be specific, there is always the use of tags such as [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) in lieu of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) alone.